# Accelerometer data and reducing noise with some filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, accelerometer, noise, kalman-filter

I've collected my data using ADXL345. In order to get rid of noise, I need to use a filter in MATLAB. I should filter the values from just one axis so it's a one dimensional array (just x-axis).

I am unsure whether to use Kalman Filter or others. I'm not familiar with Kalman Filter, it's hard to apply for me. Could you give me some idea about this issue?

edit:

Thanks for your answers. The data was already stored as you said.

```
a = [-0,63 -0,55 -1,26 -2,94 -6,39]
```

There are hundreds of values inside the array list. These are just part of them. Basically, I would like to minimize the error on the stored data. I used Arduino and ADXL345 accelerometer to get these acceleration values. After applying a filter and finding more rational results, I will have the acceleration graph of the electrical scooter. .

Comment: Have you already tried a simple low-pass filter?

Comment: Can you post a plot of your data?

Comment: "What filter should I use" is a topic sufficiently broad enough generate university courses and even graduate work. You're going to have to define your problem a bit better if you want any chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I updated the question part, thanks for your interest. I hope I can explain my question well.

Comment: Do you have any recommandations at this point ?

Answer (score 2):

Kalman filtering is a type of predictive filtering that you would use in real time, to monitor the accelerometer and predict what's going to happen to it next.

If you already have your data recorded, then it's probably not necessary to use a Kalman filter, and you might be better served using a Savitsky-Golay filter, or a low-pass filter, as mikkola suggested.

Comment: I updated the question part, thanks for your interest. I hope I can explain my question well.